# Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'audioplayer in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, apk, flutter-dependencies

i have a problem with apk building in flutter. i get this error :

```
"Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'audioplayer'."
```

what should I do ? i dont find any Answer for this problem that work for me !

```
compileSdkVersion : 30.
```

and i do not have problem in flutter Doctor.

i get this error too:

```
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `AndroidManifest.xml` files. There could be some typing mistakes when you add permissions for playing audio. If it is not the problem, change **compileSdkVersion** to **29**.

EDIT:

Even though there is no problem with your `flutter doctor -v` result, it is better to share because sometimes problems occur due to your outdated versions of frameworks and libraries. Additionally, if you are not in stable channel, often some problems may occur.

Also, try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`.